# Offline full-text-search indexing and search capability

Tags: search, full-text-search

I have a reasonably large number of text documents ( 400+ ) which contain speeches related to an organization that I am a member of. We would like to distribute a CD/DVD which contains all these speeches along with an application that allows one to search based on keyword and find speeches which are relevant to that topic.

My question is: Is there some sort of prepackaged app that can build a keyword index and allow you to search it?

If not, what is the best approach to handling this? Assume target operating system is Windows XP or higher, and .NET, Flash and the JRE are available.

I am reasonably competent with programming in C++ and PHP and I am aware of all basic and a few advanced data structures. I can do some .NET GUI programming if it comes to that, so if it's a CLI app that I have to interface with, it's not a problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If this is going on a CD/DVD I would use Lucene, its java based but there is a .net version which would work.